# Why is class that extends dict json serializable, but one that extends collections.UserDict not?

Tags: python, json

Why `class Dict(dict)` is json serializable (`json.dumps(Dict)` works), but `class Dict(collections.UserDict)`is not?

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: Possibly because the `json` module checks explicitly for instances of `dict` as opposed to `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. See [How to register implementation of abc.MutableMapping as a dict subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982946/how-to-register-implementation-of-abc-mutablemapping-as-a-dict-subclass)

Comment: Tks @martineau. I will mark buran's answer, but your link really helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [source code for JSONEncoder](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/json/encoder.py) and specifically [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/16bf9bd157c7bf5f9c60414fa8e0fe5047c55a9b/Lib/json/encoder.py#L430). It checks for `dict` and `collections.UserDict` is not instance of `dict`.

The Encodersupports the following objects and types by default:

```
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | Python            | JSON          |
    +===================+===============+
    | dict              | object        |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | list, tuple       | array         |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | str               | string        |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | int, float        | number        |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | True              | true          |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | False             | false         |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | None              | null          |
    +-------------------+---------------+
```

You can extend it to handle `collections.UserDict`

Comment: Thank you @buran

Comment: IMO you shouldn't have to extend it to handle them. It's unclear why they used `isinstance(value, dict)` instead of `isinstance(value, abc.MutableMapping)` because it's one of the main points of having abstract base classes.

Comment: What I did was define a class that extends JSONEncoder and set `def default(self,o): return o.data` on it and pass this new class as the `cls` argument of `json.dumps`

Comment: Alternatively you can pass function for `default` argument of `dump()`. e.g. in this case `default=dict` is enough, i.e. objects that are not supported by default will be passed to `dict()` function.

Comment: What if `dumps()` is called within a dependency? Ideally you should be able to add a method to the custom class that the encoder will fall back on when the object is not an instance of `dict`.