# How to make a Python MagicMock object JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, mocking

I am using a Python Mock object for a third-party package that needs to JSON serialize my mock. This means that I cannot change the invocation of `json.dumps`, so must use the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207881/19643198

```
class FileItem(dict):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        dict.__init__(self, fname=fname)

f = FileItem('tasks.txt')
json.dumps(f)  #No need to change anything here
```

The only problem is that my object is not of class FileItem, but needs to be a MagicMock. This suggests multiple inheritance, so something like:

```
class FileItem(MagicMock, dict):
    def __init__(self):
        MagicMock.__init__(self) 
        dict.__init__(self)
```

Unfortunately, multiple inheritance from both dict and MagicMock seems not to work. In case this helps make this problem easier to solve, the third-party library does not need to deserialize or even use the JSON serialized representation of the MagicMock.

Comment: you can't do that in python ;( There's a long-standing [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue35111). Basically, you cannot encode a class if you don't control the encoder. Given that a proposed solution would require exactly two lines of code, it's a bit weird this hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: monekypatching the json module, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982946/how-to-register-implementation-of-abc-mutablemapping-as-a-dict-subclass, appears to be the only known "workaround"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to consider multiple inheritance. The problem is that Python's JSON module doesn't know how to serialize certain types, like `MagicMock` (or other common types like `datetime`, for that matter).

You can tell `json` how to deal with unknown types by either using the `cls=` or `default=` parameters, but since you are asking about unit tests and don't want to modify the code you're testing, you can solve this by also mocking `json.dumps` (or `json.dump`).

For instance,

```py
import json
from json import dumps as _dumps
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock

f1 = {'fname': 'tasks.txt'}  # a normal dict
f2 = {'fname': MagicMock()}  # some value containing a MagicMock instance

def dumps_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return _dumps(*args, **(kwargs | {"default": lambda obj: "mock"}))

# mock the `dumps` function
json.dumps = MagicMock(wraps=dumps_wrapper)

# now you can serialize objects containing MagicMock (or Mock) objects
json.dumps(f1)  # {"fname": "tasks.txt"}
json.dumps(f2)  # {"fname": "mock"}
```

In your unit tests, you can use the `patch` function to temporarily patch the `json.dumps` function:

```py
# my_module.py
import json
def make_json(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj)

# test_mocked_json.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from json import dumps as _dumps

import my_module

def dumps_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return _dumps(*args, **(kwargs | {"default": lambda obj: "mock"}))

class TestMockedJSON(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_mocked_json(self):

        patch_json = patch(
            "my_module.json.dumps",
            MagicMock(wraps=dumps_wrapper))

        with patch_json:
            f1 = {'fname': 'tasks.txt'}  # a normal dict
            f2 = {'fname': MagicMock()}  # some value containing a MagicMock instance
            s1 = my_module.make_json(f1)
            s2 = my_module.make_json(f2)
            assert s1
            assert s2
            print(s1, s2, "ok!")
```

Which you can run with:

```bash
python -m unittest test_mocked_json.py

# {"fname": "tasks.txt"} {"fname": "mock"} ok!
# .
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ran 1 test in 0.001s
# 
# OK
```